# Fetch single XML node using LINQ

Tags: xml, linq, parsing

I have the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<thesaurus>
    <wordblock>
        <term type="forbidden" lang="en" termid="27561">
            <value>710 REACTOR</value>
            <historynote>Prior to May 1993, this was a valid ETDE descriptor.</historynote>
        </term>
        <dates>
            <date type="created">2000-04-12</date>
            <date type="modified">2000-04-12</date>
        </dates>
        <terms>
            <term rel="SEE" lang="en" termid="3124" type="valid">
                <value>ENRICHED URANIUM REACTORS</value>
            </term>
            <term rel="SEE" lang="en" termid="3387" type="valid">
                <value>FAST REACTORS</value>
            </term>
            <term rel="SEE" lang="en" termid="3876" type="valid">
                <value>GAS COOLED REACTORS</value>
            </term>
            <term rel="SEE" lang="en" termid="6199" type="valid">
                <value>MOBILE REACTORS</value>
            </term>
            <term rel="SEE" lang="en" termid="7969" type="valid">
                <value>PROPULSION REACTORS</value>
            </term>
        </terms>
    </wordblock>
    <wordblock>
      [...]
      [...]
      [...]
   </wordblock>
</thesaurus>
```

I am trying to parse the XML with LINQ and get specific node. In the above e.g., I need to match the value "710 REACTOR", and get the corresponding `<terms>` node inside the same `<wordblock>` node. I'm not very familiar with the LINQ syntax, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ wont be much useful in this case. What about using XMLDocument?

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load('your xml');
XmlNode node =  xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//WordBlock/term[value = '710 REACTOR']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(PATH_TO_YOUR_DOCUMENT);
var termNodes = from x in xdoc.Descendants("term") 
                where x.Element("value").Value == "710 REACTOR" 
                select x;
```